# Custom Search API for deprecated Patent Search API

Tags: google-custom-search

Google just [announced](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.de/2016/01/retirement-of-certain-google-search-apis.html) the retirement of some deprecated but pretty useful search API's, like Google Patent Search API, Google News Search API, Google Blog Search API, Google Video Search API and  Google Image Search API
and forwarded to the [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/?utm_campaign=chrome_deprication_api_011516&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=blog) as the recommended alternative.

What would now be the syntax for a patent search with the custom search API?

e.g. for
https://developers.google.com/patent-search/?utm_campaign=chrome_deprication_api_011516&utm_source=gdev
the patent-search uri will be gone.

The javascript API is the `google.search.PatentSearch` class, which I assume will also be removed.
And I don't see anything like Patent, Video or Images in the https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/ref_prebuiltlabels

Comment: `&tbm=pts` is part of the answer, the rest is looking for patent related JSON fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer at [Python module for searching patent databases, ie USPTO or EPO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028166/python-module-for-searching-patent-databases-ie-uspto-or-epo) looks like it would be helpful to you.  It gives a Python example of doing a Google patent search using the  custom search API.

Answer (score -1):

You could also switch over to using IPStreet.com.  The provide a RESTful API endpoint for basic keyword searching of patents as well as advanced semantic search algorithm (Latent Semantic Indexing). http://www.ipstreet.com/